# How to embed a Youtube video and Podcasts into an iphone app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, youtube-api

I have an app which requires the **Youtube videos and Audio Podcasts** to be played inside my app and not giving out control to youtube player or safari.

**What is the method that can be used to embed Youtube videos and Audio Podcasts into my iphone app?**

Any tutorials about the above issue are most desirable as I am new into this.

Please give ur suggestions.

Your suggestions are welcome.

**Thanks in Advance!!**

Comment: Guys Please Reply!!! I am still in search of a solution

Comment: I need to do the same. I have done playing youtube video using this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729538/youtube-iphone-displaying-uiwebview-of-video?rq=1. But I dont know how to integrate Podcast. Can you please guide me how to play podcast audio in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to embed and play videos inside your app then copy videos to your app's resource folder(.mp4 or .m4v format is desired) and use MPMoviePlayerViewController class instance to play the video. :)